# Is there a GUI for the tool fwupd (firmware updater) in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, update-manager, gui, firmware, fwupd

In [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-focal-fossa-release-notes/) a Firmware Updater is integrated, it is a GTK front end for **[fwupd](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd)**. And I wonder whether there is such thing for the Vanilla Ubuntu GNOME.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **GNOME Firmware** (gnome-firmware): Available in the Software Center (as [deb package from Ubuntu 20.04 onwards, in the universe repository*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-firmware) and snap):
   GTK front end for fwupd. It can update, reinstall and downgrade firmware on devices supported by fwupd.
   [image]
   To install it from the **command line** (Terminal):
   For the deb package (Ubuntu 20.04 and newer): `sudo apt install gnome-firmware`
   For the snap app: `sudo snap install gnome-firmware`
   There is a also [flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Firmware).
   It seems that there is still [room for improvement](https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2019/09/13/gnome-firmware-3-34-0-release/) of the app, though. Therefore it could be still better to update the [firmware from the command line](https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/).
2. For some devices, firmware updates are **directly** [listed in **GNOME Software**](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/gnome-3-18-release-new-features).
   [image]
3. **firmware-updater**
   An new firmware updater UI made with Flutter and based on fwupd is [included in Ubuntu 23.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/10/ubuntu-23-10-new-features-download-link).
   [Canonical has been working on](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/11/ubuntu-is-working-on-a-new-firmware-updater-app) this **new** firmware-updater app for some years: https://github.com/canonical/firmware-updater
   It can also be downloaded/installed [from the Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/firmware-updater) in previous Ubuntu versions, but with mixed results .

*Thank you [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) for the hint!

Comment: FYI - the deb-package is [also available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-firmware).

Comment: Thank you, @Jan for the feedback although it is not an encouraging one. At least it looks like the app is under construction as the last update was a month ago and the activity on https://github.com/canonical/firmware-updater/activity is steady although the last one is already a month ago ...

Comment: Apologies for the harsh report, my bad. I really appreciate that folks are working on it! I've been dealing with lots of bugs in software as of late, and I tilted a bit. Again apologies.

Comment: @Jan I understand your frustrations. If you like, you can always delete a comment (like I will do in a few days when you probably have read this). Cheers!